# Exporting ONNX Model from Deep Learning Frameworks at Operator-level

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, onnx

Hi, I have some questions regarding exporting ONNX models.

Let's say we have an LSTM cell from PyTorch.

Using torch.onnx.export produces ONNX model with LSTM *layer*.

However, I am interested in whether it can produce the ONNX model at the *operator* level, i.e, matmul, add.

Is there a way to do so?

If not, is there another way to make an *operator* level ONNX model?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export a model from PyTorch to onnx using the `torch.onnx.export()` function, it records all the operations that the initial model has used. as mentioned [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html).

> we call the `torch.onnx.export()` function. This will execute the model, recording a trace of what operators are used to computing the outputs.

so, yes it does produce the onnx model at the operator level, you can even visualize the exported `.onnx` model graph using [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)

[image: onnx model]

if you still want to use the `onnx` operator, [here](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/Operators.md#operator-schemas) is the ONNX Operator Schemas.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give it a shot!